# Advice for Object Detection on Embedded System with no non-standard libraries

Tags: c, object, detection, vision

I am looking for some advice for a good way to detect either square or circular objects in an image.  I currently have a canny edge algorithm running on the original greyscale and I can produce this output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwmbU.jpg

Now I can see that there is a cubesat in this picture, but what is a good computationally efficient way that the program can see that aswell?  I have looked at houghs transform but that seems to be very computation heavy.  I have also looked at Harris corner detect, but I feel I would get to many false positives, for I am essentially looking to isolate pictures that contain said cube satellite.

Anyone have any thoughts on some good algorithms to pursue?  I am very limited on space so I cannot use any large external libraries like opencv.  (This is all in C btw)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would into what is called [mathematical morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology)

Basically you operate on binary images, so you must find a clever way to threshold them first , the you do operations such as erosion and dilation with some well selected structuring element to extract areas of interest in your image.